# Parallel for loop and dbcontext savechanges method not working in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, parallel-processing, savechanges

I have written a parallel for loop in my console application like this:

```
Parallel.For(0,_allTokens.Count,index=>
{
using(var ctx = new myContextEntities())
{
 // a lot of stuff done...
userObj.Updated = true;
ctx.SaveChanges();
}
});
```

The thing here is I create a context object for each thread that is executed for my application to ensure that each user object gets its own data and that nothing gets mixed up..

My question here is:

```
- Why doesnt' the ctx.SaveChanges() method doesn't works like this ? =(
```

I understand that it is a bad practice to call SaveChanges() each time after an itteration is done, but this is required due to complex logic before this statement.

Can someone help me out , why isn't the change in code reflected in my DB by using the code like this  ? =(

P.S. before this code the list is loaded into this:

```
List<UserStores> _allTokens;
    using (var ctx = new myContextEntities())
    {
        if (Initial)
        {
            _allTokens = ctx.UserStores.Where(x => x.Updated == false).OrderBy(x => x.LastUpdatedAt).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            _allTokens = ctx.UserStores.Where(x => x.Updated && (x.UpdatedToday == null || x.UpdatedToday == false)).OrderBy(x => x.LastUpdatedAt).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Could it be possibly be related because i have two using statements ?

Ultimately I didn't wanna bug with EF anymore and good old stored procedure did the work than any EF will do ever:

```
create procedure updateuser
(
@StoreId int,
@Updated bit,
@LastUpdatedAt datetime,
@UpdatedToday bit
)
as
update UserStores 
set Updated=@Updated,LastUpdatedAt=@LastUpdatedAt,UpdatedToday = @UpdatedToday
where Id=@StoreId
```

Comment: Is there any sort of exception being thrown? Or is is just dying quietly?

Comment: @JamesRoss it just dies out quietly. No exceptions whatsoever at all. Line gets executed nicely n and all.. But when I checkin DB , change isn't refledcted... I mean it's odd , especailly because I didn't turn off any of the default EF context options ...

Comment: `DbContext` is not thread safe and should not be shared by multiple threads.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes but what if I create an instance for each thread.. Just like I did in this?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that part. Are you saying that if you convert the `Parallel.For` to simple `for` (w/o modifying the body), it's working and with `Parallel.For` not?

Comment: @IvanStoev yes exactly like that... With simple for loop works like a charm, wiht Parallel.For works as well, no errors in code but savechanges() doesn't works :(

Comment: @IvanStoev Any ideas what might be causing this ?

Comment: Not currently, I need to investigate it. It would be great if you can provide as simple repro. At the meantime, someone else could help you if has encountered the same.

Comment: @IvanStoev could you take a look into my updated question. I do have one more using statement above before the parallel for loop. Could that be the cause of error ?

Comment: You should enable logging (ctx.Database.Log =Console.WriteLine) and see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Depends. If you expand the `_allTokens` list in debugger, do you see `UserStores` objects or proxy objects? @Evk With all that threads running?

Comment: @IvanStoev well you can test on a list of two users for example.

Comment: @IvanStoev System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UserStores_E4E5920B32823937B3C313084EE1CDC8BF6E6972B60BD55D09891983DB936038 this is what it writes out

Comment: @Evk I think Ivan is onto something, it seems the objects I'm workign with ar not actual objects of my entity context, but rather some dynamic proxies which I've never heard of before honsetly

Comment: @User987 That might be the cause. Try `ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` before populating `_allTokens`. But note that looks line your entities are eligible for lazy loading (otherwise EF will not create proxies), so if your code relies on lazy loading, it will stop working. You might need to use eager loading (`Include`s).

Comment: @IvanStoev now it shows its an actual object userstore =) .. Hold on i'm trying it out now

Comment: @IvanStoev now it updates only one column that I set it... other 2 doesn't ... This is so weird o.O